# Missing quotes on UUID when using Apache Avro

Tags: java, maven, avro

I use the Apache Avro Maven Plugin to generate my Java classes from my .avsc definitions. I have some fields that are declared as UUID strings as follows:

```
{
  "name": "fieldName",
  "type": {
    "type": "string",
    "logicalType": "uuid"
  }
}
```

In Avro 1.11.0 these fields were mapped as properties of type `String` by the generator.

Starting with Apache Avro 1.11.1, the generator maps these fields as properties of type `java.util.UUID`, which is an improvement imo. However, when calling the `toString` method of a generated class with one of such fields, the output is not a valid JSON since the UUID field is not surrounded by quotes.

I have looked into the `toString` generated code, and indeed, UUID fields are not serialized with surrounding quotes.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: What makes you think the `toString()` method should return valid JSON?

Comment: The Javadoc of the method `GenericData#toString` that the generated code uses says so: Renders a Java datum as JSON.

Comment: I have also used Avro's `JsonEncoder` class and there I get the following error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.UUID cannot be cast to class java.lang.CharSequence`.